# Sorting an array using oop

Tags: php, arrays, oop

The following is a sample array:

```
array(11, -2, 4, 35, 0, 8, -9)
```

I would like to use oop to sort it and generate this result:

Output :

```
Array ( [0] => -9 [1] => -2 [2] => 0 [3] => 4 [4] => 8 [5] => 11 [6] => 35 )
```

I was provided the solution far below, which works. What I don't understand is what the `__construct` is doing. I have a beginner's understanding of how constructors work, but what specifically is the purpose of this constructor?:

```
 public function __construct(array $asort)  
 {  
    $this->_asort = $asort;
```

Is it turning the input into an array?

```
<?php  
class array_sort  
{  
    protected $_asort;  

    public function __construct(array $asort)  
     {  
        $this->_asort = $asort;  
     }  
    public function alhsort()  
     {  
        $sorted = $this->_asort;  
        sort($sorted);  
        return $sorted;  
      }  
}  
$sortarray = new array_sort(array(11, -2, 4, 35, 0, 8, -9));  
print_r($sortarray->alhsort());  
?>
```

Comment: Ola! Have you take a look at this nice function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Why do you want to "sort using OOP"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reference to the current object, it's most commonly used in object oriented code.

Here is a [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and a longer [primer](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html).

The array `$asort` is assigned to the variable `$_asort` of the class and take `$_asort` as a property of the object created.

Answer (score 0):

The `__construct()` is initialising the `protected $_asort;`. Essentially moving your array parameter into a class variable, which is then utilised by `alhsort()`.

For clarification, the **Input** as you said is already an array once you declare `array(...)` the construct simple copies it into a variable accessible by the entire `array_sort` class.

Answer (score 0):

This is way too over engineered!

Why do you want to do this oop when you can simply call

```
$sortarray = sort(array(11, -2, 4, 35, 0, 8, -9));
```

---

To answer your question, __construct() is called whenever the object is instantiated new array_sort(array(11, -2)); instantiates the array_sort object.

Your particular constructor is setting the protected property $_asort with the value passed into the first argument $asort.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
class array_sort  
{   
    public $temp;
    public function alhsort(array $sorted)  
     {  
        for($i=0; $i<count($sorted)-1; $i++){
            for($j=$i+1; $j<count($sorted); $j++){
                if($sorted[$i] > $sorted[$j]){
                    $temp =  $sorted[$i];
                    $sorted[$i] = $sorted[$j];
                    $sorted[$j] = $temp;
                }
            }
        } 
        return $sorted;  
      }  
}  
$sortarray = new array_sort();  
print_r($sortarray->alhsort(array(11, -2, 4, 35, 0, 8, -9)));  
?>
```